# How separate search results by category? MySQL + PHP

Tags: php, mysql

### Hi!

I didn't get any code that worked. Of course I could have use then wrongly because I'm a beginner. Some told me to use MySQL subqueries other told me to use PHP foreach achieve it.
What I want is to show the search results of a keyword separated by groups of categories, something like that:

> Search results for *Item*, 3 itens in 2 categories:
>
> #### Category 1:
>
> Item 1
>
> Item 10
>
> #### Category 2:
>
> - Item 1003

Can someone explain me it as simple as possible.
Thanks n advance!

Comment: You can use Group By in mysql http://www.plus2net.com/sql_tutorial/sql_having.php Or as you get the result in php you can loop it based on each row

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I use a single request which return name of category for each item and I use PHP to display it

```
<?php
    $cat;
    while($result = $statement->fetch()) {
        if($result['cat'] !== $cat) {
            $cat = $result['cat'];
            /* display cat */
        }
        /* display items */
    }
?>
```

Comment: Where do we insert this snippet?!